# How to Delete Row in Google Sheet By ID using Laravel

Tags: laravel

im try to delete row data Google Sheet by ID in Laravel. Im using this package : [kawax/laravel-google-sheets](https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets)

For Example in Column A is there ID ( 123 ), now if i want to delete row data by the ID 123, i don't know how to doing that, in the usage of the package, there no way to delete a row by id, now i'm confused to find way to delete row data

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had table with headers and I had to clean appended records. I solved my problem with this code.

```
Sheets::spreadsheet(env('POST_SPREADSHEET_ID'))
        ->sheet('DataSheet')
        ->range('A8:C50')
        ->clear();
```

You can see more details about range at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#cell